# How to perform on click action when close search in action bar

Tags: android, search

Here I want to hide Search+ button when i click on '<' button as shown bellow
how to take action when click on it is there any @override method ?
[image]

here is my code:

```
private MenuItem item2;
item2 = menu1.getItem(0); // get position of item
item2.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() { // perform on click action here

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        item2 = menu1.getItem(2).setVisible(false); // hide button
        item2 = menu1.getItem(1).setVisible(true); // enable button
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        item2 = menu1.getItem(1).setVisible(false); // hide button
        item2 = menu1.getItem(2).setVisible(true); // enable button
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This can be done using javascript document.getElementById.style.display=none.Why java tag here?Any use of java here?

Comment: @rocking I want this in android

Comment: @rocking this is android lol

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz I wrote the comment when the OP has written java tag not android tag was there

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
private MenuItem item2;
if (item.getTitle().equals("Search")) {
item2 = menu1.getItem(0); // get position of item
            item2.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() { // perform on click action here

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    item2 = menu1.getItem(2).setVisible(false); // hide button
                    item2 = menu1.getItem(1).setVisible(true); // enable button
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    item2 = menu1.getItem(1).setVisible(false); // hide button
                    item2 = menu1.getItem(2).setVisible(true); // enable button
                    return true;
                }
            });
       }
}
```

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz Actually I don't know where to add my answer. I posted my code here because may be it will useful for some who researching like me. Can you please suggest me where i can add?

Comment: If it is answer then it is fine to add it here ..so explain properly that this is answer to ur question..so instead of `I done it,here is my code:` write `I solved it using this code` or something like that

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz Ohh.. Ok thank you for your suggestion.I edited my comment about the code

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // hide your icon
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Edit: Assuming you're using Android's [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) implementation